# Define a new logical operation in Sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, logical-operators

I have been reading the source code of Sympy to try figuring out if I can add my own logical operation. This is where the logical operations are defined: 
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/logic/boolalg.py

Is it possible without modifying the library itself?
I am assuming I need to create a class that extends BooleanFunction but then in this piece of code:

```
class Boolean(Basic):
    """A boolean object is an object for which logic operations make sense."""

    __slots__ = []

    def __and__(self, other):
        """Overloading for & operator"""
        return And(self, other)

    __rand__ = __and__

    def __or__(self, other):
        """Overloading for |"""
        return Or(self, other)

    __ror__ = __or__

    def __invert__(self):
        """Overloading for ~"""
        return Not(self)

    def __rshift__(self, other):
        """Overloading for >>"""
        return Implies(self, other)

    def __lshift__(self, other):
        """Overloading for <<"""
        return Implies(other, self)

    __rrshift__ = __lshift__
    __rlshift__ = __rshift__

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return Xor(self, other)

    __rxor__ = __xor__
```

How may I add the new operation without modifying the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass `sympy.logic.boolalg.BooeanFunction` (or just `Boolean` if your object isn't going to be a function). BooleanFunction itself subclasses from Function, meaning you use the same behavior as Function to define define its operation, namely, define the classmethod `eval` which returns values when you want the object to evaluate, and None when it should remain unevaluated. See for instance the definition of [Not](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/8824e1a8647a79c5306090e003b4cfbe30cad5c7/sympy/logic/boolalg.py#L452).

If your operation is a lattice operator (as And and Or are), you can also use LatticeOp, which simplifies their definition.

As for the operator itself, if you want to overload an operator, define the `__method__` for it on your class. Python only allows overloading certain [specific operators](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), and you can't change their precedence, so depending on what your operator is, there may not be a reasonable operator that you can define for it, in which case, you will need to use the function notation.